# How can i access a div with almost all the parameters same

Tags: xpath, watir-webdriver

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="MainColumn">
    <div class="firstrow">
        <div class="sub1">Label1</div>
        <div class="Value1">
            <span class="ValueRow">
                <a href="link here">Linkname</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="Value1">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="firstrow">...</div> 
    <div class="firstrow">...</div>
    <div class="firstrow">...</div>
</div>
```

How can i click on the link named `LinkName` in the HTML above using XPath? I am working on Watir Webdriver.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't use xpath with Watir. The Watir API is designed to make it easy to reference elements in a much more readable fashion.

Comment: It would help to explain what you are having difficulty with. The question title suggests there are multiple similar div elements, yet you ask how to find a link that is unique in the provided HTML.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I dont want to access the link using Linkname as the its not unique and can change.The link sits under Label1 which is unique.Is there any way to use the Label in finding access to the link?Thanks

Comment: Since I don't know watir-webdriver, but I do know the XPath to locate the link I'll post this as a comment: `//div[preceding-sibling::div[text()='Label1']]/span/a/text()`. Alternative: `//div[.='Label1']/following-sibling::div/span/a/text()`

Comment: Thanks the second one worked for me !

Answer (score 1):

Locate it *by link text* and click:

```
browser.link(:text =>"Linkname").click
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.a(xpath: "//a[text()='Linkname']").click
```